# How can I change a var in a thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Imagine I have an instance of the thread class:

```
thr=Thread.new {
  loop {
    print var
    sleep(5)
  }
}
```

When i change the value of the variable it doesn't change in thread

This also doesn't work:

```
thr[:var]=2
```

The question is how can i change the variable in current thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread safe local variables are best off handled slightly differently [quick useful document](https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/11/20/ruby-thread-local-variables/)

```
thr = Thread.new {
  loop {
    print Thread.current[:var]
    sleep 5
  }
}

thr[:var] = "meep\n"
```

Using `Thread.current[:var]` inside the thread, you seem to be able to set the variable hash and print it out as needed.

Comment: Note that you are setting a thread-local variable there. This is not necessarily thread-safe, in that it is not necessarily safe to manipulate thread-local variables of other threads, If you need to update variables across thread boundaries, you might want to look into some of the thread-safe options of the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem.